# HTML CSS relative position not working in gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail

I was trying to prepare a newsletter, I need an image to be in the middle (in terms of height) of two line as given below
[image]

I used the below css

```
position:relative;top:-5px;
```

And it is working fine in browser, but not in gmail. Is there some way to make this work in gmail.
Thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designing newsletters are somewhat finicky with divs as support is limited for some css features across various platforms and support varies from platform to platform.

For Newsletters, I suggest that you use HTML tables tags to design your newsletter as it provides bulletproof formatting for newsletters across different email clients including Outlook and Windows 10 Mail.

I think the CSS position is not supported in Gmail. Answers to similar questions are available in StackOverflow though.

You can refer to the following link for the compatibility check
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/

Comment: Voted up as the issue of sending formatted emails is a complex one. If you do not know what email client your recipients might be using, and who does other than in very controlled environments, it is unsafe to assume many styling features will be supported, and the situation changes. Keep it simple, and provide a pure text alternative preferably for those on simpler systems, or who simply don’t want fancy stuff (and might have e.g. images switched off).